# How to copy local jars in Maven when building JavaFX executable?

Tags: jar, maven-3, javafx-8

I finally got Maven to build a JavaFX executable jar with this pom:

```
<dependencies>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-configuration</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-configuration</artifactId>
        <version>1.7</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.sf.opencsv</groupId>
        <artifactId>opencsv</artifactId>
        <version>2.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>ProtocolAnalyzer</groupId>
        <artifactId>com.protocolanalyzer.api</artifactId>
        <version>1.0</version>
        <scope>system</scope>
        <systemPath>${project.basedir}/libs/Protocol-decoder.jar</systemPath>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>ProtocolAnalyzer</groupId>
        <artifactId>bluecove</artifactId>
        <version>1.0</version>
        <scope>system</scope>
        <systemPath>${project.basedir}/libs/bluecove-2.1.1-SNAPSHOT.jar</systemPath>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>com.zenjava</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>8.1.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <mainClass>com.andres.multiwork.pc.Main</mainClass>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

    </plugins>
</build>
```

This works perfectly: I get an executable jar and a `lib` folder in the same directory of my jar where all the libraries are copied.

But I have two local jars (`Protocol-decoder.jar` and `bluecove-2.1.1-SNAPSHOT.jar`) that I added as dependencies. However, they are not being copied to the lib folder or being added in the classpath in the manifest inside the jar.

I'm new to Maven but I think that `maven-resources-plugin` is the plugin that copies the dependencies to the lib folder. How I can tell Maven or the plugin to also copy my local dependencies. Is this possible without creating a local Maven repository and adding my jars there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are looking for maven-dependency-plugin, goal copy-dependencies.

```
<plugin>
  <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
  <executions>
    <execution>
      <id>copy-dependencies</id>
      <phase>package</phase>
      <goals>
        <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
      </goals>
      <configuration>
        <outputDirectory>lib</outputDirectory>
      </configuration>
    </execution>
  </executions>
</plugin>
```

Comment: I tried adding this: http://pastebin.com/jCMtvgck and the running `clean jfx:jar` but still the libraries are not being copied

Comment: You want outputDirectory set to lib.

Comment: Ok, I set `outputDirectory` to `${build.directory}/jfx/app/lib` and all the jars are being copied but the `class-path` in the jar still doesn't include my local jars

Comment: Because scope of system means they're system-dependent. If you want those as part of the project, you need to get them in your repository (see mvn install-file), and depend on them with a normal scope. If you insist on bad practice, you can manually add lib/surname.jar entries via maven-jar-plugin.